# Removing log from production mode is not working - react native

Tags: react-native

React native documentation state that
"You can also use this babel plugin that removes all the console.* calls. You need to install it first with npm i babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev, and then edit the .babelrc file under your project directory like this"

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't find .babelrc file. Hence I made the following changes in babel.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
};
```

But it's not working for me. The logs are displayed when I've tested them in Android Studio. What went wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

This should work (**recommended method**)

```
const presets = ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'];
const plugins = ['module:react-native-dotenv'];

if (process.env.ENV === 'prod') {
  plugins.push('transform-remove-console');
}

module.exports = {presets, plugins};
```

Or if you don't want to use any package for this you can do this.
Place this in `index.js`

```
if(!__DEV__){
   console.log = () => {}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I saw method 2 is simple and faster, so what difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

The documented approach didn't work for my existing project either, but it worked in a new test project. I tried numerous dependency upgrades, adding/removing deps, plugins, etc. trying to figure out the source of the problem, but no luck. So finally I went with this workaround:

```js
    module.exports = {
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator', 'lodash'].concat(
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? ['transform-remove-console'] : []
      ),
      presets: [
        'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
        ['@babel/env', { targets: { node: 6 } }]
      ]
    };
```